# Appending multiples txt files to ONE txt file

Tags: batch-file, append

I need to take all the content in 200 TXT files and amalgamate to ONE file.

No clue how I would even start this script, any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type *.txt >"c:\one.file.will.rule.them.all.txt" 2>nul
```

just don't put the result file in the same directory to avoid strange results.Or give it another extension until all work is done.This will work if all files are in the same directory.

Comment: Tickady Boo!  Thanks Man!

Answer (score 1):

Place each of the text files you want to merge in the same folder. For ease, place them in a folder in the root of the C: drive (e.g. c:\textfiles) and make sure the folder only contains text files you want to merge.

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001376.htm